# Changes not staged for commit

Tags: git

I'm trying to commit and push my urls_index.ejs file using git, located in the views directory.

Normally I first

```
git add
git commit
git push
```

However this time Im "getting changes not commited'

```
On branch feature/user-registration
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   ../package-lock.json
    modified:   urls_new.ejs

Untracked files:
    urls_register.ejs

no changes added to commit
```

I accidentally created the git branch, how would i delete it so I can commit my code?

Comment: what do you want to delete? a file or the new branch ?

Comment: @IonutArdelean the branch

Comment: please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

to delete a git branch, simply switch to another branch before you want to delete it.
afterwards remove the branch by using this command

```
// delete branch locally
git branch -d localBranchName
```

if you pushed the branch up to the repository, you can use this command to remove it from there as well:

```
// delete branch remotely
git push origin --delete remoteBranchName
```

best of luck !